# Linqpad C#expression grouping clause

Tags: c#, linqpad

I have the [image: table]

and I want to use the Linqpad C# expression to get the result look like [image: this table]

But I cannot group the data by DayOfWeek like the table above.
Here is my code:

```
 from s in Shifts
  where PlacementContractID == 3
  select new
 {
    DayOfWeek = s.DayOfWeek,
    EmployeesNeeded = s.NumberOfEmployees
 }
```

Comment: My select statement show the Day and Number of Employee group by ShiftID, so it displays many rows for 1 day instead of 1 like table above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to do something like the following:

```
Shifts.Where(sh => sh.PlacementContractID == 3)
      .GroupBy(sh => sh.DayOfWeek)
      .Select(g => new{ 
          DayOfWeek = g.Key, 
          EmployeesNeeded = g.Sum(sh => sh.NumberOfEmployees) //maybe a cast required?
      })
```

Apologies for moving from query syntax to fluent syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I need to do the Sum() of all value in Employees needed for each day, not the Count()

Comment: @GKra : Does this change sum it up? You might want to cast from `byte` to something bigger if things start overflowing.

Comment: Yes, it works this time. By the way,can you recommend for beginner some tutorials or articles about this basic C# expression in Linqpad? Thank you